# How to prove this inequality with two variables and exponents?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

I've been trying for 2 days to prove this inequality, and I've run out of ideas. How to do it?

$$\frac{(f+c)^{f+c}}{f^f}>\frac{(1-f)^{1-f}}{(1-f-c)^{1-f-c}} , 1/2<f<1, 0<c<1-f$$

So far I've tried endless combinations of power manipulation to see if I could cancel some things which i know are bigger than 1, for instance. But I always end up with something left that I can't prove to be bigger or smaller than 1.

Comment: The inequality can be written as $\phi(x) > \phi(y)$ where $\phi(t)=t^{t}(1-t)^{1-t}$, $x=f+c$ and $y=f$. [It looks like](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5Et+(1-t)%5E(1-t)) $\phi(t)$ is increasing for $\frac{1}{2} < t < 1$.

Comment: I suppose you intended $\frac12< f< 1$ in your conditions.  With the condition written as is, there is nothing to prove ;).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As $x\log x$ is convex for $x> 0$, we may use [Karamata's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) and just show $(f+c, 1-f-c) \succ (f, 1-f)$, which is true for the conditions which imply $\frac12< f< c+f< 1$.

Comment: I was looking for an algebraic proof, but this is definetly a proof, thanks. Is there any way to prove it is "greater" and not "equal or greater" than, since c is never zero? Also, c is not greater than f, but the proof holds.

Comment: As $x \log x $ is strictly convex and $(f+c, 1-f-c) \neq (f, 1-f)$, the inequality is strict as well.

Comment: Also you're right, we do not need $c> f$, just $f < f+c$ is enough for the majorization.  Will make that edit.